# Angular2 with angularfire2

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Hello I have an issue with installing angularfire2 with angular2 released version .here is the snapshot

[image]

here is my package .json

[image]

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install @types/request@0.0.30 for the recent Angular 2 release.

```
npm install @types/request --save
```

As for your `fsevents` incompatibility, it looks like it's an issue of your node version based on this [issue report](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10768). According to that thread, it looks like it won't cause a problem it's just a warning. I would recommend updating your node to the newest version to see if that gets rid of the warning.

Comment: FYI, you cannot get rid of the `fsevents` warning, as that module is not compatible with Windows. Ignoring it is the way to go.